# localview changes viewport in blender , how to disable it?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, settings

H i , Local view or ( / ) hotkey changes view port (zooms out or in or rotates the scene) , is there any way to disable this behavior ? I want my viewport to remain still when im working .

It is cool though but in some situations it just not needed .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  There is an option, 'frame selected', that you can change in the shortcut by going to the keymap panel of preferences and finding the *Local View* shortcut:

[image: Local View in Preferences Keymap]

"Frame Selected" may be "grayed out" but if you click on the checkbox to unset it, it will deselect.

Comment: I must speed up my image editing... :^)

Comment: Who did it first ?  can i leave this one to staff or community to accept the answer ? thanks both of you btw

Comment: @user256371.  According to the "answered N mins ago" tag on the answer I was about 6 minutes faster than John, but 'accepted' should go to the _best_ answer, not the quickest, so if you think John's more comprehensive answer was better you should award it to him rather than me.

Comment: You can give that one to @Marty Fouts since he beat me by 6 minutes. :^)  Incidentally his final comment about leaving it enabled for one of the shortcuts doesn't seem to work as I mentioned in my answer! That's why it took me so long as I was checking how it worked!

Comment: @JohnEason if my answer is less comprehensive than yours, then you should get the check.  Meanwhile I'll remove the erroneous comment.

Comment: @MartyFouts No problem. It looks as if both entries should be enabled/disabled together so that seems to be a display bug!

Comment: @MartyFouts can i ask you please consider comments below this answer as an exception and not to remove them cause this becomes a kinda of diary for us

Comment: @user256371 I don't understand why you are making that request.  The only comments I can remove are my own and I haven't done that.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the framing (zoom, etc.) in the keymap editor. Search for <kbd>local</kbd> on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keymap Tab</kbd> and uncheck <kbd>Frame Selected</kbd> under either of the <kbd>Local View</kbd> <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> entries as shown below.[image]
I suspect there might be a bug there because I'd have expected it to only disable that action for one of the keypress types (main keyboard or numpad), but in fact unchecking either will disable framing for both although the other one is still checked.

Comment: I saw the answered time , and it seems like martyfouts did it 7 mins faster , although your answer was more comprehensive , and very much thank you . ♥♥♥